# Three js how to cancel mouse click after clicking on HTML overlay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, user-interface, three.js

I currently have the following problem using Three.js:

I created to do my own HTML user interface, doing it as a simple overlay.
The problem is, whenever I click an element on this overlay, the mouse click wont get resetted.

To describe it: When I click on my "Camera Init" button, the camera gets in its position, but as I move the mouse my camera is moving, too. So, when I click on the HTML element the click wont get released until I click a second time somewhere else in the scene. I checked it out using the `'mousedown'` and  `'mouseup'` events. Both events trigger and my console log tells me that I released the mouse button. Still I have to do a second click on the scene to "cancel" the mouse hold, which makes all interactions a pain.

This is a strange behaviour and I cant find any solution to this. Maybe there is a way to access and cancel the mouse click manually which I just doesnt know anything of?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

HTML Code for a simple button:

```
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary ui-button" id="button-cameraInit" >CAMERA INIT</button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#button-cameraInit {
  position: absolute;

  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Adding the event listener in the scene.js :

```
document.getElementById('button-cameraInit').addEventListener('click', cameraInit, false);
```

And the CameraInit function:

```
function cameraInit() {
  camera.position.copy(camStartPosition); // x=33, y=66, z=100

  // Using OrbitControls
  orControls.target.set(0,0,0);

  orControls.update();

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}
```

Init of the OrbitControls:

```
orControls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  orControls.autoRotate = false;
  orControls.enableKeys = false;
  orControls.enableZoom = true;

  // Set mouse button binding here
  orControls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY, // go to OrbitControls.js, line 348 to change zoom direction
    RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN
  };

  orControls.update();
```

Comment: Could you share us your codes? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated my question now, hopefully it's enough

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question, but answer may help someone.

Create variable, that changes its value if mouse cursor is in/out HTML element.
For value change you can use `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` event.

Now in raycast function just run the code or return depending on value.